# Expected number of Half corners in a plane.

Tags: probability

**Let S be a set of points in the plane. A point in S is a half-corner if there is no other points in
S that is both above and to the right of it. Suppose each point in S is chosen independently and
randomly from the unit square [0::1]  [0::1]. What is the expected number of half-corners in S ?**

Does anyone has any idea about how can we solve this problem?

My professor has added a hint also, but I am unable to get it. The hint is below:

[image]

Comment: How many points are in S?

Comment: Its generaized...S points..i guess.

Comment: you have a discrete number of points, that changes it

Comment: @Stefanos: how, can you explain in some simple language please

Comment: For example, if there is only 1 point, the probability is 1.

Comment: @rubberchicken That is correct for 1 point, it will be 1, but how can be scale it for n points, because i am not able to think, how will i calculate probability for other points which are far from the rightmost point.

Comment: Can you post please the whole exercise and not only the hint? We need the distribution of $Y_i$ in order to proceed.

Comment: @Stefanos There is no more data, hint i have posted as image and the question i have changed to bold

Comment: Then I will interpret the randomly as uniformly

Answer (score 4):

Fleshing out the hint:  the rightmost point is certainly a half-corner-there are no points to the right of it.  The next to rightmost is a half-corner with probability $\frac 12$, because it can only be beaten by one other point.

Added:  the point of the hint is to notice that the chance the rightmost point is a half-corner is $1$.  The next to rightmost point has $\frac 12$ chance of being a half-corner, because it will be one if its $y$ coordinate is greater than that of the rightmost.  The third to rightmost will be a half-corner with probability $\frac 13$ as it has to be the greatest $y$ of three points.  The $n^{\text{th}}$ rightmost will be a half corner with probability $\frac 1n$.  The sum of these is that the expected number of half corners among the $n$ rightmost is $H_n$, the $n^{\text{th}}$ [Harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), about $\log n + \gamma$

Comment: But there are infinite possibilities here, how will i decide the number of points? and the probability will vary as we move away from the rightmost point.

Comment: I think you are supposed to assume a finite set.  You are right, the probability changes as you move away.  What is the chance for the third point?  Use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: I got it. But, one question i have, in any case there can be only one half corner. So, what are we trying by this question? Is it the probability of each point to become a half corner? because even through linearity of expectation i think it will come to something like 1 + no. of points next to point with max y (1/2) + no. of points next to those (1/i). If 1<=i<n. Am I going correct?

Comment: No, you can have all the points being half corners-say they are all on the line $y=1-x$  It sounds like you don't have the hint yet.

Comment: Hmm, now i also feel the same. I am getting confused.

Comment: I think you are just confusing the probability and the expcted number of points. For the first two points there is guaranteed to be at least one-the rightmost.  There are two with chance $\frac 12$.  The expected number is then $\frac 32$.  Then what is the chance that the third is a half-corner?

Comment: @Stefanos:  the hint talks about the rightmost-that is the one with greatest $x$ coordinate.  It is guaranteed to be a half-corner

Comment: @Stefanos:  no the second rightmost only has to beat the rightmost in y.  It will beat all the other points in x.

Comment: Ok, yes because he defines $p_1$ to be the rightmost point and not the 1st point. Sorry I am too tired and I make silly comments. Sorry for your time, nice solution. +10